# JHipster blueprint context

Tags: jhipster, code-generation, yeoman

I am newbie in JHipster, encountered a problem with the visibility of the context in the JHipster blueprint.
What I've done:

1. Created a blueprint and inserted the project from node-modules/.../generators/angular into the Angular templates.
2. Changed the template _entityFile.component.html
3. Inserted the path to the template in the write method of the generator:

```
        get [AngularGenerator.WRITING]() {
        return this.asWritingTaskGroup({
          ...super.writing,
          async writingTemplateTask({ application }) {
            await this.writeFiles({
              sections: {
                files: [{ templates:  ['/src/main/webapp/app/entities/_entityFolder/list/_entityFile.component.html.ejs'] }],
              },
              context: application,
            });
          },
        });
      }
```

But when I apply this blueprint to the project, the following error occurs:
[occured error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsvtG.png)

The generator doesn't even see the context of JHipster itself. Why? Can anyone make a small guide on how to work with JHipster's context and how to add your own context?

I don't try anything, for me docs are not full enough. ChatGPT advised me to inject jhipsterContext into my app, but it's not working